# Detecting when a row is not full in Isotope and adding an Item to fill it

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I am using the Isotope plugin to layout tiles of differing sizes and I am using the filter functionality to show hide some of these tiles.

It is multi select filtering so you can select several of the filters at the same time, the problem here is that you don't know what content you are going to get back and so there are often blank spaces at the bottom like so: [image: gap left by Isotope layout].

I need to do 3 things here:

1. Detect if a row is not "full", i.e. after layout has any gaps in it
2. Get the size and position of the gap
3. Push some spare content of the right size into this gap

I know Isotope has an addItem method that I can use for step 3 but after much googling and reading up on the Isotope docs I am no closer to a solution for 1 & 2.

Has anyone come across this issue before and have any ideas how to go about this.

Comment: One easy way to 'appear' to fill the gap is with a colored/image background - ensure all tiles have no gap between them, use border to create the illusion of whitespace between them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the default `masonry` layout mode, which may produce gaps. Try using the [`packery` layout mode](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html), which is designed to fill gaps.